# Why do I see the result as True and False .agg() pandas python function?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Quick question.When I ran this code, I see TRue or False as a break down. Why so?

datamart.groupby(datamart['RFM_Score'] == 9)['MonetaryValue'].agg(np.mean)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBo8F.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote returns the result of a comparison as True or False.  Looks like a comparison of whether each value is above the mean or not.

Looks like you want the mean of only the rows with RFM_Score == 9.  If so, filter your df to only those rows, then get the mean of those rows.  See this toy example:

```
row1list = [8, 1]
row2list = [9, 2]
row3list = [9, 4]
datamart = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list], columns=['RFM_Score', 'MonetaryValue'])

datamart1 = datamart.groupby(datamart['RFM_Score'] == 9)['MonetaryValue'].agg(np.mean)
print(datamart1)
# RFM_Score
# False    1
# True     3

datamart9s = datamart[datamart['RFM_Score'] == 9]
mean_of_money_for_9s = datamart9s['MonetaryValue'].agg(np.mean)
print(mean_of_money_for_9s)
# Name: MonetaryValue, dtype: int64
# 3.0
```